# reuse copper water line for fridge

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, copper, copper-tubing

My current fridge uses copper water line. I ordered a new fridge from Costco and it will be delivered in the next couple of days. Costco offers free haul away and simple installation. I highly doubt that they will connect the water line for me because of the copper line (they may do so if it were braided water line). I'd like to know the standard process of dealing with existing copper water line when installing a new fridge. Here is my guessing:

1. The current copper water line may have memory and can break easily. Suppose I'm lucky that the line is fine,so that I can reuse the line.
2. I guess the old compression connection can't be used, i.e. I think I need to cut the head of the copper line after disconnecting it from the old fridge, and then do a reaming.
3. Connect the copper line to the fridge with a new compression nut.

Are the above steps correct? Is it true that the old copper line can't be reused?
Does anyone know what Costco crew usually do with an existing copper line?

Answer (score 2):

If the new fridge connects with a standard compression fitting, you unscrew the fitting on the old fridge, slide it out, slide in the new fridge, and screw the fitting into the new fridge.

There is **no need nor benefit** in cutting off the end of the line with the old compression fitting. If it works now, it should work with a new fridge. Compression fittings are made to be crimped on (by the fitting itself) the first time they are connected, and used hundreds of times after that without need of replacement. Do not over-tighten them.

If the connection is in a wildly different location, you may need to carefully bend (without kinking) the old copper line to reach it.

Comment: I disagree, you never want to reuse a compression fitting.  It is already deformed and may leak.

Comment: A braided water line is different from a copper water line: the former comes with a nut but the latter is just bare copper. See https://www.costco.com/wcsstore/CostcoUSBCCatalogAssetStore/Attachment/Kitchen_Install_Requirements.pdf

Comment: Look behind your fridge. You'll find a nut. It's part of the compression fitting that connects the tube to the fridge...it has been on that bare copper since the compression fitting was tightened the first time, and will be there until the line is cut - pointlessly if the new connection is also a compression fitting of the same size/type. I cannot be removed any other way.